# How to load a huge data set into newly created table?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I'm trying to FULLTEXT index into my table. That table content 3 million records.It was very difficult to insert that index using Alter table statement or Create index statement. Therefor easiest way to create new table and 1st add index and load the data. How can I load existing table data into newly created table? I'm using Xammp MySql database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why creating a full text index on an existing table would be difficult.  You just do:

```
create fulltext index idx_table_col on table(col)
```

Usually, it is faster to add indexes to already loaded tables than to load data into an empty table that has indexes pre-defined.

EDIT:

You can do the load by using `insert`.  The following will insert the first 100,000 rows:

```
insert into newtable
    select *
    from oldtable
    order by id
    limit 0, 100000;
```

You can put this in a loop (via a stored procedure in MySQL or at the application level).  Perhaps this will return faster.  Each time you run it, you would change the offset value in `limit`.

I would expect that the overall time for creating an index would be less than using `insert`, but for your purposes, you might find this more convenient.

Comment: I am not sure about that - index creation can lock the table from being used. Therefore there is a special case when you may want to create table seperately and load data into it with index already created and then just switch tables. But I understand this is a very special case and is rather runtime-change oriented.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Actually when I'm trying to create index using Alter table statement my browser creating and just waiting and stuck my machine. Heat and ram goes to about 70%. I don't know the reason. Is that the reason my table contains about 3 million?

Comment: How big is the column you are creating index on?

Comment: @Uhla column contain 3 million records varchar(1000) type. Huge time consume and my ram goes to 70%. Have you tried to add FullText index to large amount data set using create index statement?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanx. "overall time for creating an index less" .I also think that. But what's the reason when I'm trying to use creating statement, browser just retrieving show connecting and take huge time. Now about more than 10 minute. Is that any reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable;
```

After your new table and index on it is created.
This is given you want to copy all columns. You can select specific columns as well.

Comment: Where I put column names of newly created table?

Comment: This syntax is assuming that new table has same column names and types as the old table. 
For more information, see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp